# How to get filename for a class in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have access to a Class ("AnyClass") object, and would like to get the file name for this class.

Tried searching online but couldn't find it anywhere. Is this possible in Swift?

EDIT: My use case (described in a comment below)

I'm collecting unit test metadata and mapping test ownership via `.github/CODEOWNERS` file. However, at runtime, unit test hooks (`XCTestObservation`) only has access to the class name of the test that is running, and the class name does not map to CODEOWNERS in any way. I would be able to map my repo's CODEOWNERS to the tests much easier if I just had the full path of the file that the unit test is running for.

Comment: print(#file)???

Comment: @RajaKishan that's the currently running class, but I have an `AnyClass` object from another location

Comment: It shouldn’t matter at runtime which file a particular class came from - during compilation this data is essentially lost, as it doesn’t matter for the resulting binary - in the end noone stops you from having all your code in a single file - the end binary would be the same. Given that - may I ask why would you want this? Maybe the core issue can be handled differently?

Comment: @Losiowaty I'm collecting unit test metadata and mapping test ownership via `.github/CODEOWNERS` file. However, at runtime, unit test hooks (XCTestObservation) only has access to the class name of the test that is running, and the class name does not map to CODEOWNERS in any way. I would be able to map my repo's CODEOWNERS to the tests much easier if I just had the full path of the file that the unit test is running for.

Comment: Hmm, ok. From this description it sounds like maybe trying to get this data from code coverage tools / similar to how these tools get it might be a better approach  They do show code that was hit in relevant files, but that may require to run your test suits in isolation to be certain that test T hit file F… I cannot offer any advice going further, unfortunatelly - it seems like an intersting case and I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1):

```
protocol NameObject {
var className: String { get }
static var className: String { get } }

extension NameObject {
var className: String {
    return String(describing: type(of: self))
}

static var className: String {
    return String(describing: self)
}}

extension NSObject : NameObject {}
```

Copy and paste above code and then on any class just use YourViewController.className / YourView.className

Comment: I have access to the class name already, but my goal is to get the file name that this class is inside. (e.g. MyClassName.swift). It's not guaranteed that the Class Name identically matches the file name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Rishabh Shukla gave me an idea for a possible approach, though its not straightforward and requires jumping through a few hoops.

So the idea would be to create a protocol :

```swift
protocol FileNameProvider {
  var filename: StaticString { get }
}
```

And then leverage [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) - it will allow you to generate implementation for this protocol for each type. I think that the inline code generation approach would be best here, so your template would look something like this :

```
// in template:

{% for type in types.all %}
// sourcery:inline:{{ type.name }}.TemplateName
extension {{ type.name }}: FileNameProvider {
  var filename: StaticString { return #file }
}
// sourcery:end
{% endfor %}

// in source code:

class MyType {

}

// sourcery:inline:MyType.TemplateName
// it should generate the code here
// sourcery:end
```

The downside of this is that you would need to manually (or via another script ) add

```
// sourcery:inline:MyType.TemplateName
// sourcery:end
```

for each type in your codebase, which could be a lot.

Sourcery has the ability for automatic inlining, [but apparently it has some problems at the moment when there are multiple types defined in a file](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/issues/601) and it seems from [the docs](https://cdn.rawgit.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery/master/docs/writing-templates.html) that it adds the code at the end of the type, so it won't be possible to add protocol conformance this way as an extension.
So while this approach would save you from adding the `inline` annotations manually, it seems it's not feasible at this moment - or maybe it just requires more creative tinkering with the templates - like adding the implementation inline, but creating the empty extension declaration in a separate file from another Sourcery template .

The end goal of all of this would be to then use it as simply as

```swift
(object as? FileNameProvider)?.filename // if `object` type is Any/AnyObject
object.filename // if `object` type is directly from your codebase
```

Disclaimer : I was not able to test this approach at the moment of writing this, so your mileage may vary.